# Code Editor Similar to Coda

Tags: 12.04, text-editor, interface, html

Hi I am looking for a code editor similar in interface and features to coda.
Mainly I do not want a program that looks like it has not been updated since 1900's.
I am trying out Sublime but am hopping for an interface more similar to coda.

Thanks,
Leinardo

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read in a few forums in just the past couple of minutes, it seems that there have been people looking for a Coda alternative on Linux and haven't been able to find one. Eclipse is rather good, but I choose to stick with Sublime myself. Just like any other editor, it takes some getting used to.. but eventually, you can power through it (sometimes better than a fully developed IDE).